# How can I dd a VMware disk's contents to a FAT partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, mount, vmware, dd

I haven't used `dd` to transfer data between filesystems with different formats before, and I thought I'd post what I have. I am trying to convert a virtual machine with the disk in files under the virtual machine directory (bootable only through VMware) to the same disk imaged to a FAT filesystem partition (bootable, I hope, either through VMware or natively). The one I am working on now has a 200G slot allocated via Mint's tools for custom allocation, and I am trying to copy a 200G VMware disk. (I could give it 1 or 2 more gigs if needed.)

The best shot I've had so far is:

```
christos@christos-laptop ~/Windows 10 x64 6.vmwarevm $ sudo dd if=Virtual\ Disk.vmdk of=/dev/sda3 count=214748364800 bs=1024
dd: error writing '/dev/sda3': No space left on device
2+0 records in
1+0 records out
1024 bytes (1,0 kB, 1,0 KiB) copied, 0,0011087 s, 924 kB/s
```

It's possible AFAIK that a previous attempt clogged the partition, and I've had an ancillary problem mounting and possibly erasing the disk:

```
# mount -t vfat /dev/sda3 /tmp/windowsmount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda3,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

So, what (if anything) can I do to clear the partition of anything that will be recognized as taking up space, and after the wipe image it will the disk image contents?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure `dd` can be used for the purpose. What I know is the target shouldn't be a partition. `dd` is typically used to write images to drives and it replaces whatever is written there with a raw data copy including the partitions structure.

Comment: I mentioned `dd` rather than e.g. `cat`. `dd` stands for 'device to device [copy]', is explicitly intended to be low-level, and it should be able to modify at least some `/dev/sd*` files.

Comment: (`dd` might still be the wrong tool for what I intend, but using `dd` to attempt to modify an unmounted disk partition is not in and of itself something to avoid doing.)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Is your goal to copy a virtual disk partition to a physical disk partition?  If so, can't you add a physical disk the VM and then have the guest use `dd`?